# Angular order by not working with dates type

Tags: angularjs

I have to order elements in a list by last modified date with angular.js 1.5. I do the ordering this way:

estate in estates | order by 'lastModifiedDate'

where lastModifiedDate is attribute in estate.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not sort the elements correctly. 
I get the dates from the server in this format:

```
estates: [
{
lastModifiedDate: 1479321747932
},
{
lastModifiedDate: 1479321747972
},
{
lastModifiedDate: 1479321748033
},
{
lastModifiedDate: 1479321748082
},
{
lastModifiedDate: 1479321748129
}
]
```

The last object should be first but it sets it to be last in the ui.

Comment: The correct format of orderBy in angular is `ng-repeat="estate in estates | orderBy: '-lastModifiedDate'` with a '-' to have descending order instead of ascending. Check this [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) out. I believe in your case it is doing a numeric comparison in which 1479321748129 should be last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHyeoI9M2IpmLfehjlw3) to sort the `lastModifiedDate` in a correct way.

You can either use:

```
ng-repeat="estate in estates | orderBy:'lastModifiedDate':true"
```

or

```
ng-repeat="estate in estates | orderBy:'-lastModifiedDate'"
```

to sort the estates in descending.